When should I disclose that a feature is only available after a plan purchase in a form?
I'm working on a form that includes a feature available only after purchasing a plan. Should I inform users about this restriction upfront, or is it better to reveal this information at the end of the process?
My thinking is that if users invest effort into filling out the form, they might be more likely to pay. However, I’m also concerned about transparency and user trust. What has worked best for you in similar situations?

It might depend on how much effort is required to complete the form.

Disclose the availability of premium features early and often, at the appropriate points in the user journey. This prevents frustration, builds trust, and can even encourage users to upgrade by making the value proposition clear.
That being said, if you also want to, do rethink referring to below points. This is how we scrutinized such a case about an year ago.

Before Interaction: Label features as "premium" to avoid wasting users’ time.
At Interaction: Inform users with a pop-up or inline message when they try to access a paid feature.
Summary/Confirmation: Highlight locked features before submission.
Onboarding: Clearly differentiate free vs. premium features upfront.
Promotions: Always indicate if a promoted feature requires a paid plan.
Plan Downgrade: Notify users of features they’ll lose upon downgrading.

